# Can' access content of an array in react-native

Tags: javascript, sqlite, react-native

I'm trying to get data from a SQLite Database in React-Native (android). The function returns an Array with data.
If I try logging the array to the console, it works fine, but when I log the length of the Array to the console, it suddenly prints "0".

Functions:

```
getActByButton(category) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            const activities = [];
            const request = 'SELECT activity FROM activity_button WHERE category = ? AND activity IS NOT NULL';
            this.initDB().then((db) => {
                db.transaction((tx) => {
                    tx.executeSql(request, [category]).then(([tx, results]) => {
                        //console.log('Query COMPLETED');
                        var len = results.rows.length;
                        for (let i = len; i > 0; i--) {
                            activities.push(results.rows.item(i - 1));
                        }
                        resolve(activities);
                    })
                }).then((result) => {
                    this.closeDatabase(db);
                })
            })
        })
    }

    getIconByAct(activity_ids) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            const icons = [];
            const request = 'SELECT name, icon FROM activity WHERE id = ?';
            this.initDB().then((db) => {
                db.transaction((tx) => {
                    for (let id in activity_ids) {
                        tx.executeSql(request, [id]).then(([tx, results]) => {
                            console.log('Query COMPLETED');
                            var len = results.rows.length;
                            let icon = results.rows.item(0).icon;
                            let description = results.rows.item(0).name;
                            icons.push({ icon, description });
                        })
                    }
                    resolve(icons);
                }).then((result) => {
                    this.closeDatabase(db);
                })
            })
        })
    }
```

Function-call:

```
db.getActByButton(this.props.category).then((data) => {
    result_ids = data;
}).then(() => {
    db.getIconByAct(result_ids).then((data) => {
        console.log('DATA:');
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.length);
        console.log(data[1]);
    })
})
```

Console:
[image]

How is this possible?
And how can I fix it?

Comment: Make sure that when you log `data` it's *actually* filled in. The console is lazy-evaluated so it's possible that *at the time* when you called `console.log(data);` it was empty and when you expanded it *later* it now has data. You can try logging `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` or `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)));` this will make a copy of the data at the time of logging.

Comment: `resolve(icons);` is executed long before all those queries finish. To run multiple SQL queries and do something with the result, use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: Thanks, that's the problem. It seems to be enough to move ```resolve(icons)``` into the ```executeSQL(request, [id])```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.getActByButton(this.props.category).then((data) => {
    result_ids = data;
}).then(() => {
    db.getIconByAct(result_ids).then((data) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data.length));
    })
})
```